# Did (other) officials from EU countries condemn Trump's tariffs on Turkey?

Tags: united-states, european-union, international-relations, turkey, germany

Assuming [this](https://ahvalnews6.com/turkey-sanctions/german-economy-minister-blasts-trump-over-trade-row-turkey) is not fake news:

> Germany's minister for economic affairs and energy on Sunday lashed out U.S. President Donald Trump over his trade row with Turkey, while accusing him of dictating Europe's dealings with Iran through renewed U.S. sanctions, Ulusal news website reported. [...]
>
> Altmaier said that Germany stands with Turkey against the U.S. sanctions, noting, ‘’Turkey represents security and credibility in Europe and we have a very successful cooperation with Ankara in migration. The elections are over in Turkey and now we have the opportunity to resume serenity and objectivity.’’

Did officials from other EU countries side with Turkey, or at least condemn the recent US (extra) tariffs on Turkey?

(As far as I can tell Ahval, the site reporting this, is [banned in Turkey](https://stockholmcf.org/turkish-government-bans-access-to-critical-ahval-news-website/), so it's probably not a mouthpiece of the Turkish government. Although it could still be fake news.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the source you quote and to a lesser degree your question difficult because of language like "lash out" and "condemn." This is a value judgement about what was said which seems not supported by the sources.

- Peter Altmaier gave an interview to the tabloid newspaper *Bild am Sonntag*. In this interview, he talked about US sanctions and tariffs in general and also in specific -- notably against the EU, China, Iran, and also Turkey.
- He mentioned that as secretary for economic affairs he represents 7,000 German companies doing business in Turkey, and that "we want Turkey to be a stable and democratic country." He also said that Turkey knew "we do not compromise in the protection of German citizens."
- There have been other EU leaders who emphasized that "[a strong Turkish economy is in the EU interest](https://www.handelsblatt.com/politik/international/steven-mnuchin-us-regierung-droht-der-tuerkei-mit-neuen-sanktionen/22922212.html?ticket=ST-6579385-dbfPreGMjeEIoJ4KdcFp-ap3)".
- Here is another article from [Politico.eu](https://www.politico.eu/article/recep-tayyip-erdogan-europe-watches-as-turkey-lira-currency-burns/) explaining (their interpretation of) the EU viewpoint.

I wouldn't characterize that as *siding with Turkey* or *condemning the recent tariffs on Turkey.* Turkey is part of a pattern and **that** concerns the EU.

---

**Follow-Up:** In the news today (2018-AUG-19), Andrea Nahles (from the SPD, the junior coalition partner in the German government) suggests that Turkey might **need** emergency assistance from the EU to prevent an economic breakdown. The way it is phrased suggests that such assistance might be granted. (The conditions were not specified.)

Comment: My impression was also that Ahval may have been editorializing too much... but I wasn't sure since I couldn't find/read the full interview with Altmaier.

Comment: @Fizz, the full interview seems to be behind a paywall of the newspaper.